How to send a buffers between 2 GPU's?
I trying to allocate buffer A and buffer B to GPU 0 and then allocate them (buffer A and buffer B) to GPU 1 and run them the a kernel that adds A + B and allocates it to buffer D (that I allocated before in GPU 1)
my issue is that it does not work in Python, PyCuda, or CuPy.
I am searching for some examples of it (PyCuda, or CuPy).
I tried this code in PyCuda, and that works, but I can't prove that it allocates the buffer on GPU1
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import numpy as np
import time

cuda.init()

array_size = 1000000
h_a = np.random.randint(0, 101, size=array_size).astype(np.float32)
h_b = np.random.randint(0, 101, size=array_size).astype(np.float32)
h_c = np.random.randint(0, 101, size=array_size).astype(np.float32)

dev0 = cuda.Device(0)
ctx0 = dev0.make_context()
ctx0.push()
d_a_gpu0 = cuda.mem_alloc(h_a.nbytes)
d_b_gpu0 = cuda.mem_alloc(h_b.nbytes)
d_c_gpu0 = cuda.mem_alloc(h_c.nbytes)
cuda.memcpy_htod(d_a_gpu0, h_a)
cuda.memcpy_htod(d_b_gpu0, h_b)
cuda.memcpy_htod(d_c_gpu0, h_c)
ctx0.pop()

dev1 = cuda.Device(1)
ctx1 = dev1.make_context()
ctx1.push()
d_a_gpu1 = cuda.mem_alloc(h_a.nbytes)
d_b_gpu1 = cuda.mem_alloc(h_b.nbytes)
d_c_gpu1 = cuda.mem_alloc(h_c.nbytes)
ctx1.pop()

ctx0.push()
start_peer_transfer = time.time()
cuda.memcpy_peer(d_a_gpu1, dest_context=ctx1, src=d_a_gpu0, src_context=ctx0, size=h_a.nbytes)
cuda.memcpy_peer(d_b_gpu1, dest_context=ctx1, src=d_b_gpu0, src_context=ctx0, size=h_b.nbytes)
end_peer_transfer = time.time()
ctx0.pop()

kernel_code = """
__global__ void add_arrays(float *a, float *b, float *c)
{
    int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (idx < 1000000)
    {
        c[idx] = a[idx] + b[idx];
    }
}
"""

mod = SourceModule(kernel_code)
add_arrays = mod.get_function("add_arrays")

block_size = 256
grid_size = (array_size + block_size - 1) // block_size
ctx0.push()
start_gpu0_kernel = time.time()
add_arrays(d_a_gpu0, d_b_gpu0, d_c_gpu0, block=(block_size, 1, 1), grid=(grid_size, 1))
cuda.Context.synchronize()
end_gpu0_kernel = time.time()
ctx0.pop()

ctx1.push()
start_gpu1_kernel = time.time()
add_arrays(d_a_gpu1, d_b_gpu1, d_c_gpu1, block=(block_size, 1, 1), grid=(grid_size, 1))
cuda.Context.synchronize()
end_gpu1_kernel = time.time()
ctx1.pop()

h_c_result = np.empty_like(h_c)
h_d_result = np.empty_like(h_c)
ctx0.push()
cuda.memcpy_dtoh(h_c_result, d_c_gpu0)
ctx0.pop()

ctx1.push()
cuda.memcpy_dtoh(h_d_result, d_c_gpu1)
ctx1.pop()

comparison = np.allclose(h_c_result, h_d_result)
print("Results are identical:", comparison)

print(f"Time for cuda.memcpy_peer: {end_peer_transfer - start_peer_transfer:.6f} seconds")
print(f"Time for kernel execution on GPU 0: {end_gpu0_kernel - start_gpu0_kernel:.6f} seconds")
print(f"Time for kernel execution on GPU 1: {end_gpu1_kernel - start_gpu1_kernel:.6f} seconds")

d_a_gpu0.free()
d_b_gpu0.free()
d_c_gpu0.free()
d_a_gpu1.free()
d_b_gpu1.free()
d_c_gpu1.free()
ctx1.pop()
ctx0.pop()

For CuPy I tried this code that return an error on "deviceCanAccessPeer"
import cupy as cp
import numpy as np
import time

try:
    with cp.cuda.Device(0):
        A = cp.random.rand(1000)
        B = cp.random.rand(1000)
        C = cp.empty_like(A)
        
        start_time = time.time()
        
        C = A + B
        
        C_cpu = cp.asnumpy(C)
        
        print("Device 0 computation time:", time.time() - start_time)

    if cp.cuda.runtime.getDeviceCount() > 1:
        cp.cuda.runtime.deviceCanAccessPeer(1, 0)
        cp.cuda.runtime.deviceEnablePeerAccess(1)

    with cp.cuda.Device(1):
        D = cp.empty_like(A)
        
        start_time = time.time()
        
        A_device1 = cp.empty_like(A)
        B_device1 = cp.empty_like(B)
        
        cp.cuda.runtime.memcpyPeer(A_device1.data.ptr, 1, A.data.ptr, 0, A.nbytes)
        cp.cuda.runtime.memcpyPeer(B_device1.data.ptr, 1, B.data.ptr, 0, B.nbytes)
        
        D = A_device1 + B_device1
        
        D_cpu = cp.asnumpy(D)
        
        print("Device 1 computation time:", time.time() - start_time)

    comparison = np.array_equal(C_cpu, D_cpu)
    print("Comparison result:", comparison)

except cp.cuda.runtime.CUDARuntimeError as e:
    print(f"CUDA Runtime Error: {e}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")



This is a pretty confusingly written question, such as it is one. In the space of three sentences you tell us that the PyCUDA code you posted doesn't work, does work, and that you don't know how to prove it works. Which is it? And what is your actual question here? And it is about cupy (which you detagged, but left code) or PyCUDA? If you clarify these points, someone might be able to provide you with a useful answer

It would also be useful to provide information about the platform you are running on, in particular the GPUs you are using, windows vs. linux, and the motherboard topology - whether the GPUs can even be placed in a peer relationship or not.
